# PHP seems to ignore my curl.info of my php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, ini

I'm using WAMP on Windows with several version of PHP. The one I currently use is PHP 7.3.12. After following carefully every step of installing the `cacert.pem` file into my WAMP folder, my PHP does not seems to see it. Here's the step I've taken to install it:

- I downloaded the `cacert.pem` file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
- I moved this file into my `extras\ssl` folder of my PHP folder (`C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`)
- I wrote this absolute path into the `php.ini` file from WAMP, after `curl.cainfo` (and I removed the `;` caracter), by left-clicking the WAMP icon>PHP>php.ini. This file is located here: `C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini`.
- Then I restart my WAMP services and it literally copy this file on the `php.ini` file of the PHP version I'm currently using here: `C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.12\phpForApache.ini`.

Even after theses steps, PHP do not seems to see my cacert file because when I try to `dd(ini_get('curl.cainfo'))` if give me this: [image: ini_get('curl.cainfo') dump]

Just to be sure, I looked into my `phpinfo()` in the curl section:[image: phpinfo() curl section]

But when I dumped my `php.ini` file with this command `dd(file_get_contents(php_ini_loaded_file()));`, I can clearly see my `curl.cainfo` path:
[image: php.ini file dump curl section]

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but when using GuzzleHTTP from my Laravel projet, I tried giving the library an absolute path `$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => 'C:\dev\wssp\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.12\extras\ssl\cacert.pem']);` and it worked. I still want to be able to use it with the `php.ini` file for environnement purpose.

Comment: This might be a better fit on server fault: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sadly, I asked the same question on ServerFault, but people seems to say that because WAMP is involved, this is a dev problem, thus that should be on StackOverflow. I might try to reformulate my question so it can be answered via SO.

Comment: Oh, shoot! Well thanks for the update. I guess I was wrong!

Comment: In your `phpinfo()`, I believe it should tell you what `php.ini` file is being loaded. Make sure that you're modifying the right file.

Comment: As my code suggested, I dumped my php.ini file and you can see on the picture above that what I need is actually here. Thank you for the hint anyway.